The universal cover of a complete noncompact Riemannian manifold with ${\rm Ric}\geq0$ that contains no lines also contains no lines.
I am reading On loops representing elements of the fundamental group of a complete manifold with nonnegative Ricci curvature by Sormani. She proved the following theorem:

Theorem. If $M$ is a complete noncompact Riemannian manifold which does not satisfy the geodesic loops to infinity property, then there is a line in its universal cover.

In this question we needn't to know what the geodesic loops to infinity property is. Then Sormani claimed that we have the following consequence of the above theorem:

Corollary. If $M$ is complete noncompact with ${\rm Ric}\geq0$ and there exists $p\in M$ such that ${\rm Ric}_p>0$, then $M$ has the geodesic loops to infinity property.

Here is my understanding about the corollary:
If $M=N\times\mathbb R$, then ${\rm Ric}(\partial_t)=0$, where $t$ is the coordinate of $\mathbb R$. Therefore if there exists $p\in M$ such that ${\rm Ric}_p>0$, then $M$ can't split as $N\times\mathbb R$ for some $N$ with ${\rm Ric}_N\geq0$. By the Splitting Theorem, $M$ contains no lines. But to apply the theorem, we need to know the universal cover of $M$ contains no lines.
So does the universal cover of a complete noncompact Riemannian manifold with ${\rm Ric}\geq0$ that contains no lines also contain no lines? Any help would be appreciated!
Edit:
A line $\gamma : (−\infty,\infty) \to M$ is a minimal geodesic satisfies $d(\gamma(t), \gamma(s)) = |t − s|$ for all $s, t \in\mathbb R$, i.e. it is defined on the whole $\mathbb R$ and always minimal between any two points on it.

You may want to explain what is meant by a line.

@MikhailKatz A line $\gamma : (−\infty,\infty) \to M$ is a minimal geodesic satisfies $d(\gamma(t), \gamma(s)) = |t − s|$ for all $s, t \in\mathbb R$, i.e. it is defined on the whole $\mathbb R$ and always minimal between any two points on it.

A complete hyperbolic metric of finite area on a once punctured torus contains no lines, but its universal cover certainly does, so the Ricci curvature hypothesis here is essential.

Denote by $\tilde M$ the universal cover of $M$. If $\tilde M=N\times\mathbb R$, then ${\rm Ric}(\partial_t)=0$.
Since there exists $p\in M$ such that ${\rm Ric}_p>0$, we have that there exists $\tilde p\in\tilde M$ such that ${\rm Ric}_{\tilde p}>0$ (since $\pi:\tilde M\to M$ is a local isometry, and Ricci curvature is a purely local concept). A contradiction. So $\tilde M$ can't split as $N\times\mathbb R$ for some $N$ with ${\rm Ric}_N\geq0$. By the Splitting Theorem, $\tilde M$ contains no lines.
